# foreach loop: loop variable can't be modified after assignment (?)

Tags: c#, regex

I have following code:

```
string STR = "AA ABC AA AA ABC aa aa aa AA" ;  //declare string

Regex rx = new Regex(@"AA"); // declare regular expression

MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(STR);  // find matches in STR

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    // perform sub-string operations that changes the original string
    STR = "AA AA ABC aa aa aa AA" // substring operation which arbitrary changes the string

    matches = rx.Matches(STR);  // perform matching operation again
    // because original string is changed

    //   ERROR : 'matches' in for loop is not changed (?)

    // Question: how can I change 'matches' in for loop, thus it will start 
    // to work in new modified string ?       
}
```

Can anybody help me to solve above ?

EDIT:

```
int j = 15
for (int i = 0 to j){

// change both i and j value arbitrarily

i = 100
j = 102

changes is reflected in original for loop
}
```

In the first case I want that change reflection. However, changes in 'matches' is not reflected in foreach loop. This is the problem. How to solve it ?

Comment: in `for` loop you can change, but you use `foreach`

Comment: Modify the code to be a `function` that takes in a string (your `STR`), and when you want to change `matches`, call that function with the new string.

Comment: Modifying the foreach collection is wrong but your code runs just fine for me. The new value is assigned to matches four times.

Comment: @nima, change the line STR = "AA AA ABC aa aa aa AA"  with some sub string operation which arbitrary changes the string

Answer (score 1):

You are enumerating over `matches`, so if you change `matches` you are changing the enumeration WHILE you are enumerating over it. Of course this doesn't work and you need a new variable to hold the changed `matches`.

Comment: that's not the case. the value of matches variable was changed, not matches itself. the code does not throw exceptions, it just behaves differently than author had expected

Comment: @lisp: It's just not a good idea to enumerate over the same variable you are trying to change in the `foreach`-loop. "Behaves differently than author had expected" can be interpreted as "doesn't work", right? ;)

Comment: it's true, that the original code was "bad", but the problem is not what you described.

Answer (score 0):

You should not modify the object you are currently iterating over: first create a copy of the original object and then apply the changes to the copy.

Answer (score 0):

Just use two variables for `Matches`. 1 for use in for each loop.. The other modified as you wish. Or Use basic for loop with counter. You cannot modify a collection actively used (foreach loop).

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure what your trying to achieve, but I think recursion might help you. This way your loop body will run on all original matches and if the string changes, it will run on all new matches too. Be aware of infinite recursion though.

```
void ForEach(Regex rx, string str)
{
    foreach (Match match in rx.Matches(str))
    {
        // code that might change str

        // if(the str was changed)
            ForEach(rx, str);
    }
}
```